# How to break an unknown ciphertext - transposition of some kind

Tags: cryptanalysis, transposition-cipher

I've been challenged to crack a code. All I know about it is that is was hand-enciphered, and that it is a transposition cipher of some kind. When I was given it, I started plugging it into my permutation decryption engine. As you can guess, when I realised that the ciphertext was 26 letters long, meaning permutations numbering $26!$ I stopped the program and scratched my head. What would the most efficient way to crack this be?

Unable to find an answer, I turned to Crypto.SE. Can anybody explain an efficient way to crack the cipher?

Comment: We haven't got any information on your algorithm. Breaking (cracking) a cipher consists of performing cryptanalysis on the (expected) algorithm. Without this, I would say that you are asking how to identify and crack ciphertext known to have been created with **a** transposition cipher. I guess this is too broad; the best way may be to either 1. puzzle or 2. test any attack on any transposition cipher.

Comment: Well, it's a reasonably short cipher - only 26 characters as the Q states, but it's probably some form of key based columnar transposition.

Comment: Can you include the actual ciphertext?

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that it is a transposition of some kind you can chek
the average frequency with which the various letters appear in the natural language of the plain text and then compare them to the frequencies of letters in the cyphertext. You can easily find this data on google, [here is the example for english](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html).
This method works only if the transposition of the letters is always the same, for example: letter $n$ of the ciphertext = letter $n$ of the plain text + 10.
If your key use columnar transposition you need to work out the column lengths by dividing the message length by the key length. Then you can write the message out in columns again, then re-order the columns by reforming the key word.